# Кириллические символы некорректно отображаются в файле

Tags: python

Есть json от api, который я успешно парсю и вывожу в консоль. Захотел сохранить результат в файл, а он мне выдает крякозябры

```
–Р—А—В–µ–Љ–Њ–≤–∞ –Ф–∞—А—М—П –Р–ї–µ–Ї—Б–∞–љ–і—А–Њ–≤–љ–∞
```

На одном из сервисов декодировал текст

```
x-mac-cyrillic, x-mac-ukrainian utf-8 Артемова Дарья Александровна
```

Код

```
try:
   inc_class(token,branchid,userid,newgrade)
   print(j["name"]+"  "+ str(newgrade))    
   with open('ok.txt','a',encoding='utf-8') as f:
       f.write(j["name"]+u"\n")
except Exception:
   with open('error.txt','a',encoding='utf-8') as f:
       f.write(j["name"]+u"\n")
```

Comment: записываешь в utf а читаешь в каком формате? проблема в блокноте. можно добавить bom, но лучше используй современный блокнот

Comment: @eri не думаю что проблема в этом

Answer (score -2):

Преобразовал текст в `utf-8` и все заработало

```
with open('ok.txt','a') as f:
    f.write(j["name"].encode().decode('utf8'))
```

Comment: Что-то как-то бредовенько и каргокультно решение выглядит. Сочетание encode-decode в нормальных условиях не должно менять вообще ничего - видимо у вас данные внутри j изначально порченые